# Network ACL's on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have 2 interfaces and have enabled ipforwarding so my Ubuntu server is fully functional as a router. My question - does Ubuntu support networking (not file or directory) ACL's, ala Cisco like? I wanted to configure a standard ACL, and an extended ACL. However it doesn't seem to be possible??

Comment: Cisco's ASAs are a little different in that each object, etc. gets a network object assigned to them and then firewall rules set up.

With the proper knowledge of `iptables` and advanced networking rules, you can indeed replicate this type of thing.  It requires more understanding however of the differences between Cisco IOS/ASA and how `iptables`/`nftables` works, and how to order the rules.  However, this is an **extremely** advanced concept that may not be able to be explained fully here in a Q/A post, becasue the concept of "ACLs" doesn't exist the same way.

Comment: Thank You Thomas.